# bind9 local network ; cannot ping fqdn

Tags: bind

how is this possible?

from client:

the following works:

```
ajonen8940@aj-ThinkPad-T60:~$ host ubuntumedia.ubuntumediagz.local    
ubuntumedia.ubuntumediagz.local has address 192.168.1.104
```

this does not work:

```
ajonen8940@aj-ThinkPad-T60:~$ ping ubuntumedia.ubuntumediagz.local
ping: unknown host ubuntumedia.ubuntumediagz.local
```

this works:

```
ajonen8940@aj-ThinkPad-T60:~$ ping ubuntumedia
PING ubuntumedia.ubuntumediagz.local (192.168.1.104) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ubuntumedia.ubuntumediagz.local (192.168.1.104): icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=4.31 ms
```

Here is my resolve.conf on the client:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
search ubuntumediagz.local
```

here is nslookup:

```
$ nslookup ubuntumedia
Server:     127.0.0.1
Address:    127.0.0.1#53
Name:   ubuntumedia.ubuntumediagz.local
Address: 192.168.1.104
```

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: just found my own answer. at the client do this:

Here is the solution: perform this on client machine... or just change your suffix. http://andrewgdotcom.wordpress.com/2007/09/28/avahi-and-dot-local-addresses-on-ubuntu-gutsy/

This only applies to .local ... figures.

Comment: It might also be good to add that the use of .local as part of a domain name is not recommended! You can find a lot of info here : http://serverfault.com/questions/17255/top-level-domain-domain-suffix-for-private-network (I too believed it was common practice)

Answer (score 0):

in your /etc/hosts file

add `192.168.1.104 ubuntumedia.ubuntumediagz.local ubuntumedia`

Comment: You bypass bind using your `/etc/hosts` file...